# Constructing a safe dynamic query using SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, tedious

I am new to using the nodejs mssql/tedious library. I have a table that uses default values for columns and I can't expect logs to always have all these values present. I am wondering if there is an easier way to safely construct a query dynamically based on which values are passed to my log function.

```
const sql = require('mssql')
const config = require('config')

const dconfig = config.database

const addLog = async (options) => {
  const { text, sentSuccess, isError } = options
  try {
    let pool = await sql.connect(dconfig)
    let request = await pool.request()
    request.input('message', sql.Text, text.trim())
    if (sentSuccess) {
      request.input('sent', sql.Bit, !!parseInt(sentSuccess))
      await request.query('insert into dbo.MApp_Logs (message, sent_success) values (@message, @sent)')
    } else {
      await request.query('insert into dbo.MApp_Logs (message) values (@message)')
    }
  } catch (err) {
    throw err
  } finally {
    sql.close()
  }
}
```

You can see that here I am forced to rewrite the query several times based on which values are present. Is there a more elegant way to handle this without concatenating the values into the string?

Comment: Several times = twice? For a start use Parameters to pass values in as they protect you against SQL Injection attacks and take the pain out of needing to know whether or not to quote a value. However the more general solution is to create a stored procedure, to which you pass the relevant parameters and the SP works out what form the insert statement needs to take to respect your defaults.

Comment: There are other columns that can be accounted for. I left them out for simplicity.  Can you explain what you mean by Parameters?

Comment: Check the help https://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/parameters.html

Comment: Thanks. I was looking here before: https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#readme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really dislike using or relying on `DEFAULT` constraints in SQL other than for backward compatibility; but that is a matter of taste and preference.  I would favor handling your default values in code for new work, and always send the same SQL statement:

```
 request.input('message', sql.Text, text.trim())
 if (sentSuccess)
     request.input('sent', sql.Bit, !!parseInt(sentSuccess))
 else
     request.input('sent', sql.Bit, theDefaultValue)
 await request.query('insert into dbo.MApp_Logs (message, sent_success) values (@message, @sent)')
```

However, if you really want to use SQL's default definitions, you can always contatenate the sql statement and continue to parameterize:

```
 request.input('message', sql.Text, text.trim())
 let sqlFields = "insert into dbo.MApp_Logs (message"
 let sqlValues = ") values (@message"

 if (sentSuccess) {
     request.input('sent', sql.Bit, !!parseInt(sentSuccess))
     sqlFields += ", sent_success"
     sqlValues += ", @sent"
 }

 await request.query(sqlFields + sqlValues + ")")
```

Comment: Yikes - that looks worse than the original from a clarity and maintenance perspective.

Comment: Thanks. I always am torn when deciding to use code or my database to handle scenarios like this. It makes sense to keep the database as straightforward as possible.

Comment: I'd put that complexity in the database, and use a stored procedure which can pass in the same set of parameters every time, but the SP decides how and when to use them. Its data integrity related, and therefore not a problem (IMO) to keep in the database. It also means you can modify it without having to rebuild your code.